# solving with numerical methods

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

Hi I would like to solve the equation below in Mathematica.Since I am a beginner I can not solve it with NSolve and Solve.I don't know why.Do you have any idea?!

> `[v ^2 Log[Cosh[1/v]] == 1, v]`

Comment: `Plot[v^2 Log[Cosh[1/v]], {v, -100, 100}]`

Comment: Your equation has no *real* solutions, as I think @Dr.belisarius suggested, but you can numerically find a *complex* solution using e.g. `FindRoot[v^2 Log[Cosh[1/v]] == 1, {v, I}]`, which returns `{v -> 0. + 0.690887 I}`.

Comment: thanks @MarcoB that works I simplified  my equation here, when I solved the mean equation with your method it worked and I'm getting real solution too.

Comment: Then you must be doing something wrong.